# Letter occurence counter program not holding strings inputted by the user

Tags: python

I am creating a program that counts the occurrences of each letter in the alphabet that are in the string the user inputs. The user is prompted to keep entering strings until they enter `<end>` which stops the input and analyzes the inputs.

The analyzing works just fine. The problem occurs when, for example, I enter the first input "thanks", and then the second input, "please". The program will only analyze "please" and not "thanks". I can't figure out why.

```
programrun = True        
while programrun:
  stringinput = input ("Enter a sentence or word <END> to finish: ").lower()

  if stringinput != "<end>":
    stringinput1 = stringinput

  letters =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
  #print (programrun)

  if stringinput == "<end>":
    programrun = False
  
#stringinput2 = stringinput1
  
print (stringinput1)

for i in range(0,26): 
#frequency = (int(stringinput.count(letters[i]) / 26) * 100)
  length = len(stringinput1)
  print(letters[i],": ",stringinput1.count(letters[i]), " Freqency: ", (float(stringinput1.count(letters[i]) / length) * 100))
```

Comment: Could you indent your code properly ?

Comment: you should write last  for loop inside the while

Comment: You are overwriting stringinput before you analyze it. Try using letters as keys in a dictionary, and value as occurence, therefore no need to declare the whole alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the indentation, the `for` loop was not inside the `while` loop, so after inputing one word, the code stops, I've add other improvements

- you can just use a string with the letters instead of a list, and define it before the loop
- iterate directly over each letter, not over ints then access by index
- stop the code it the input is `"<end>"` don't do other string manipulation

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

while True:
    stringinput = input("Enter a sentence or word <END> to finish: ").lower()

    if stringinput == "<end>":
        break

    for letter in letters:
        length = len(stringinput)
        count = stringinput.count(letter)
        print(letter, ": ", count, " Freqency: ", (count / length) * 100)
```

Comment: Sorry for the format. Its indented correctly in VSCode, but that somehow didn't transfer to here. Sorry again and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think because, you need to concatenate all entries in stringinput1:

```
stringinput1="" 
while programrun:
    stringinput = input ("Enter a sentence or word <END> to finish: ").lower()

    if stringinput != "<end>":
        stringinput1 = stringinput1+stringinput

...
```